# Resizing Logical Volume

Tags: linux, arch-linux, lvm

I had a logical volume root that was 20GB and another logical volume (named Boobies, yes I know it's childish) with 200GB. I downsized the other to 100GB and extended the root to 120GB.
[image: lvs result]

But the root directory is still just 20GB.
[image: df result]

The root logical volume gets mounted as / in fstab. How do i get my system to recognize the resized root?
Running arch btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend the filesystem also.

For `ext3,4` you can use command:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/central-root
```